# DOM PDF is not working when loading Codeigniter's view file

Tags: pdf-generation, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I am trying to create PDF file using DOM pdf and Codeigniter. I have the following script in my Controller and I have kept the DOM folder inside my controller . But when I run the script I get fatal error message.

But when I send a value from my model to DOMPDF's $html which is in my controller .. I can generate the pdf.

Could you please kindly help me how to get rid of this error?

```
    include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
    $html= $this->load->view('view_pdf');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape" ); 

    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("my_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

This is my View File ;

```
<html>
 <head>
<style>
    #header { position: absolute; left: 0; top: -50px; right: 0; height: 140px; text-align:  center;  }
    #footer {position: fixed ; left: 0px; bottom: -20px; right: 0px; height: 30px; font-size:10; }
    #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }


        #table-6 {
        width: 100%
        border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
        }
        #table-6 tbody {
        /* Kind of irrelevant unless your .css is alreadt doing something else */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
        }


        #table-6 td {
        padding: 3px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align:center;
        }
        #table-6 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #F2F2F2;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        }




 </style>

  </head>

    <body>


     This is a test 
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CodeIgniter documentation on views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) you have to modify your call to load->view() so that the data is returned as a string to the controller rather than pushed to the web browser. Try modifying your controller code as follows:

```
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$html= $this->load->view('view_pdf','',true);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape" );

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("my_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

The only change I made was to add the necessary parameters to `$this->load->view()`.

(I don't use CodeIgniter. Do any CI users have anything to add?)

Comment: Thank BrianS for your reply. I tried your code but the result is the same.. I am getting the same error message. But I have found a way to get my problem solved and that is .. instead of using the "View" I use Model to generate my pdf. I am keeping the entire script inside a variable and then returning the variable to my controller. and then it generates the PDF... :) Thanks.. and just to answer your question.. CI users do not have anything else to add ... unless they have created another folder inside the view.. :) thanks again. BrianS

Comment: @Srijon try the code again. I had to modify my answer because the last parameter for `$this->load->view()` was incorrect, it should be true instead of false.

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
$this->load->view('view_pdf');
$html = $this->output->get_output();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape" ); 
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("my_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```